# Saving a character so it can be opened in a seperate blender project

Tags: texturing, materials, export, import

This is very probably a noob question, but.  I have made a couple of characters on Make human, then imported them to blender where i had to re-assign all of the textures etc.  Once i got the character looking right again, I saved it as a .blend file, as well as a collada and an Obj file thinking one of them was bound to work right.

Well, long story short, when i imported my character into my scene, all my materials and textures were back to default and in need of resetting.

I'm not sure if i am doing something wrong in my saves, if I'm saving to the wrong format, or if it is something i have yet to even think of. I'm using cycles as my render engine)

Anyone wanna help me out and give me the idiots guide to how to save your textured character so that when you import it it is all ready to go?

seems that what i have found thus far is very time consuming each time you want a new character in your scene.

Comment: You have mentioned import and save.  There are menus called import and save on the blender program.  Do you mean using those menus?  I am trying to understand more clearly. You saved your reassigned/fixed textures and saved to a .blend file.  Next is written "i imported my character to my scene".  Do you again mean the menu import of Blender?  Do you mean you blender file link or blender file append?  Do you just open the newly created blender file?  I am trying to be clear on your latter use of the word [import]... Once you fix the textures do you want to remain in blender only? Or Switch?

Comment: OK some clarification.  I built my scene and saved it to one blend file. I built my character and textured it in a seperate instance of blender and hen saved that character as .blend, .collada and .obj files.

When I go back to my other .blend file which contains my "set" (i.e. an interior in which i wish to film) I cannot find a way to bring my character in to it without it losing all of it's materials and textures again and them having to be reassigned.

Comment: So you would be satisfied to use Blender format only?

Comment: Is your question answered?

Comment: I havent tried it yet, but it does seem to make sense.

Answer (score 1):

File/Link or File/Append will be useful.

Save your character as a .blend file.  From the "set" file use the menu option File/Append or File/Link. You will get the best results when when Append or Link from one .blend file to another .blend file.  File/Append ... File/Append is a great way to reuse and asset and animation across files.  Linked Libraries.  Link below.

The blender terminology for this is File/Append or File/Link.  Import is probably not what you want.

When you File/Append ... Choose the object or Mesh or Armature or Group.  You will travel through a hierarchy  to find what you need. Blender will also link/append related items.  You can design Groups to be linked/appended.

See this link.
http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Data_System/Linked_Libraries