# Movie Clip, Symbol, Container

Tags: animation

Is there a possibility to use a symbol, container or a movie-clip in programs like After Effects, Flash, Illustrator?

The element needs to have it´s own timeline and can be reused on other scenes inside blender?

Comment: Please expand on the kind of fuctionality you are looking for. For animating elements so a search for "actions" and the "actions" editor, for video you can create nested clips using compound clips.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/16436/saving-a-character-so-it-can-be-opened-in-a-seperate-blender-project/16450?s=1|23.1709#16450